# Loading more rows after click event in Sortable Table Material UI table and React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm making a sortable table component using Material UI and React.
The functionality that I want to implement is

- Sortable table with 4 rows
- When user click a 'LOAD MORE', 4 more rows will be shown up below the default data.

Currently, I added another `renderRows()` after first one. It shows 8 rows in a table. But the data is sorted by each `renderRows()`.

Image 1 Default page

[image]

Image 2 After click event

[image]

Code

```
// properties of TableHeader component
let headerProps = {
enableSelectAll: false,
displaySelectAll: false,
adjustForCheckbox: false
};

 // initial set of rows, simulating data from the database
 let rows = [
 {date: "12:30 12.9.2017", payment: "MasterCard", narrative: "restige 
Cosmetics, Total Intensity Eyeliner Long Lasting Intense Color, Deepest 
Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)", amount: "$912.51", uniqueId: 0 },
{date: "11:30 12.9.2017", payment: "Visa", narrative: "Total Intensity 
Eyeliner Long Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)", 
amount: "$744.51", uniqueId: 1 },
{date: "13:30 12.9.2017", payment: "PayPal", narrative: "Eyeliner Long 
Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)", amount: "$12.51", 
uniqueId: 2 },
{date: "20:30 12.9.2017", payment: "MasterCard", narrative: "Long 
Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)", amount: "$16.51", 
uniqueId: 3 }
 ];

// our table hader information, key is the name of the 
// property to sort by when the header is clicked 
let headers = [
{name: "", key: "checkbox"},
{name: "Today", key: "date"},
{name: "Payment", key: "payment"},
{name: "Narrative", key: "narrative"},
{name: "Amount", key: "amount"}
 ];

 // our table component that can sort columns
 class SortableTable extends React.Component {

 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {rows, 
              sortBy: 'firstName',
              tableOpen : false
            };
  }

 handleClick = (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();
 this.setState({
  tableOpen : !this.state.tableOpen
 })
}

renderHeaders(){
let header= headers.map( (h) => {
  return <SortableHeader 
            key={h.key}
            name={h.name}
            onClicked={()=>this.updateSortBy(h.key)} 
            isSortColumn={this.state.sortBy == h.key}/>
});
return <TableRow>{header}</TableRow>;
}

renderRows() {
return this.state.rows.map( (row, i) => <UserRow {...row} key=
{row.uniqueId}/> );
 }

updateSortBy(sortBy){
  // multiple clicks on the same column reverse the sort order
  if( sortBy == this.state.sortBy ){
    this.setState( {rows: [...this.state.rows.reverse()]} );
    return;
  }

  let rows = [...this.state.rows];
  rows.sort( (a,b) => {
    if (a[sortBy] < b[sortBy])
      return -1;
    if(a[sortBy] > b[sortBy])
      return 1;
    return 0;
  });

  this.setState({rows, sortBy});
}


 render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <MuiThemeProvider>
    <Table>
      <TableHeader {...headerProps}>
          {this.renderHeaders()}
      </TableHeader>
      <TableBody>
        {this.renderRows()}
        {!this.state.tableOpen ? this.renderRows() : "" }
      </TableBody>
    </Table>   
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  <p className="openTable" onClick={this.handleClick} >LOAD MORE</p>
  </div>
  );
 }
}



function SortableHeader(props){
let style = {
cursor: "pointer"
}
if(props.isSortColumn){
style.fontWeight = "bold";
style.color = "black";
}

return (
  <TableHeaderColumn>
  <div style={style} onClick={() => props.onClicked()}>{props.name}
  {props.name==""? "" :<img src={arrowUpDown} alt="arrowUpDown" 
  className="arrowUpDown"/>}</div>
  </TableHeaderColumn>
  );
 }


 function UserRow(props){
 return (
 <TableRow>
  <TableRowColumn><img src={Check} alt="Check" className="Check"/>
 </TableRowColumn>
  <TableRowColumn>{props.date}</TableRowColumn>
  <TableRowColumn>{props.payment=="Visa" ?  <img src={Visa} alt="Visa" 
  className="Visa"/> :  (props.payment=="PayPal" ?  <img src={Paypal} 
  alt="Paypal" className="Master"/> :  <img src={Master} alt="Master" 
  className="Master"/>)}


  {props.payment}</TableRowColumn>
   <TableRowColumn>{props.narrative}</TableRowColumn>
   <TableRowColumn>{props.amount}</TableRowColumn>
   </TableRow>
 );
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updateSortBy()` method is only sorting what's currently in `this.state.rows`, so calling `renderRows()` twice will simply render the sorted set one after the other.

You probably want to have the LOAD MORE click event add more rows to the state, that way the sort and render methods are acting upon the full set of data, rather than two instances of the data.

Something like this...

```js
// properties of TableHeader component
let headerProps = {
    enableSelectAll: false,
    displaySelectAll: false,
    adjustForCheckbox: false
};

// initial set of rows, simulating data from the database
let rows = [
    {
        date: "12:30 12.9.2017",
        payment: "MasterCard",
        narrative: "restige Cosmetics, Total Intensity Eyeliner Long Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)",
        amount: "$912.51",
        uniqueId: 0
    },
    {
        date: "11:30 12.9.2017",
        payment: "Visa",
        narrative: "Total Intensity Eyeliner Long Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)",
        amount: "$744.51",
        uniqueId: 1
    },
    {
        date: "13:30 12.9.2017",
        payment: "PayPal",
        narrative: "Eyeliner Long Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)",
        amount: "$12.51",
        uniqueId: 2
    },
    {
        date: "20:30 12.9.2017",
        payment: "MasterCard",
        narrative: "Long Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)",
        amount: "$16.51",
        uniqueId: 3
    }
];

// our table hader information, key is the name of the 
// property to sort by when the header is clicked 
let headers = [
    { name: "", key: "checkbox" },
    { name: "Today", key: "date" },
    { name: "Payment", key: "payment" },
    { name: "Narrative", key: "narrative" },
    { name: "Amount", key: "amount" }
];

// our table component that can sort columns
class SortableTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rows,
            sortBy: 'firstName',
            tableOpen: false
        };
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        // create a new array containing the old and new rows
        const newRows = [...this.state.rows, ...rows];

        this.setState({
            tableOpen: !this.state.tableOpen,
            rows: newRows // update the state with the new rows
        })
    }

    renderHeaders() {
        let header = headers.map((h) => {
            return <SortableHeader
                key={h.key}
                name={h.name}
                onClicked={() => this.updateSortBy(h.key)}
                isSortColumn={this.state.sortBy == h.key} />
        });
        return <TableRow>{header}</TableRow>;
    }

    renderRows() {
        return this.state.rows.map((row, i) =>
            <UserRow {...row} key={row.uniqueId} />
        );
    }

    updateSortBy(sortBy) {
        // multiple clicks on the same column reverse the sort order
        if (sortBy == this.state.sortBy) {
            this.setState({ rows: [...this.state.rows.reverse()] });
            return;
        }

        let rows = [...this.state.rows];
        rows.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a[sortBy] < b[sortBy])
                return -1;
            if (a[sortBy] > b[sortBy])
                return 1;
            return 0;
        });

        this.setState({ rows, sortBy });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MuiThemeProvider>
                    <Table>
                        <TableHeader {...headerProps}>
                            {this.renderHeaders()}
                        </TableHeader>
                        <TableBody>
                            {this.renderRows()}
                            {/*no need to call this.renderRows() twice*/}
                            {/*{!this.state.tableOpen ? this.renderRows() : ""}*/}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
                <p className="openTable" onClick={this.handleClick} >LOAD MORE</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}



function SortableHeader(props) {
    let style = {
        cursor: "pointer"
    }
    if (props.isSortColumn) {
        style.fontWeight = "bold";
        style.color = "black";
    }

    return (
        <TableHeaderColumn>
            <div style={style} onClick={() => props.onClicked()}>{props.name}
                {props.name == "" ? "" : <img src={arrowUpDown} alt="arrowUpDown"
                    className="arrowUpDown" />}</div>
        </TableHeaderColumn>
    );
}


function UserRow(props) {
    return (
        <TableRow>
            <TableRowColumn><img src={Check} alt="Check" className="Check" />
            </TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{props.date}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>
                {
                    props.payment == "Visa" ?
                        <img src={Visa} alt="Visa" className="Visa" /> :
                        (
                            props.payment == "PayPal" ?
                                <img src={Paypal} alt="Paypal" className="Master" /> :
                                <img src={Master} alt="Master" className="Master" />
                        )
                }

                {props.payment}
            </TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{props.narrative}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{props.amount}</TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
    );
}
```

Comment: I added your solution and I got an error in my console. ''  flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `.$3`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used." I added another data set calls `rows2` with different ID. Then it worked. Thank you for guiding me a right way.

Comment: The error you see is probably coming from the `renderRows()` method because you are using the `row.uniqueId` value as the key for the component. This good practice, but since you are duplicating your data set, you will be reusing unique IDs. Realistically, this data will come from an external data source where all the IDs are unique and you will avoid this error.